# Can I compile C using Visual C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, compilation, mingw

I'm developing an education system in C, on Visual Studio. I'll support this service through a web server.

The issue is that my server runs a Linux operating system. Can I compile C code using Visual C on Linux? It will have to compile to a Windows executable file (*.exe).

Through a search I got the answer: "You can compile C with MinGW". However, I have used many Windows APIs and I don't trust this answer. (_beginthreadex, FillConsoleOutputCharacter, CreateConsoleScreenBuffer and stuff).

Do I have to develop with MinGW if I want to compile C code to a Windows executable on a Linux system?

Comment: Are you really seeking to complicate your life? Linux has plenty of native development tools. Use them.

Comment: How big is your software (in thousands of source code lines)? Is it [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly by "I'll support this service through a web server". Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot. Add several paragraphs explaining what your system does and how big it is.

Comment: Also explain in a few words why is it an education system. For me, that means the organization of schools (and other [formal education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education#Formal_education) facilities), and I don't understand the relation to software.

Comment: Also, explain in a few words who would use your software, and how (thru a browser?)

Answer (score 2):

> Can i compile C using visual c on Linux?

No, in practice you cannot (and certainly you should not). BTW, if you stick to some C standard like [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) or C99 or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) you probably don't care much about a particular compiler.

> But i used many windows apis

As you have guessed, these [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)s are *specific* to  [MicroSoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), and you cannot get (or use) them on Linux (and you probably need a Microsoft license to run a program using WinAPI). Be aware that [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is able to run on Linux *some* Windows [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (but you probably can't use that thru some web server).

You should use POSIX threads ([here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) is a good tutorial) - or perhaps consider coding in C++11 and using its [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) library (since the C11 [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) library is too recent on Linux - and probably on Windows too!).

My recommendations:

- if your program is some HTTP server, consider using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (or perhaps use [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) to make your application communicate with some other web server). If  you go that way, become familiar with [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (& [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and other web technologies, e.g. [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))).
- if your application wants a terminal interface (not a web one!) use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)
- if your application wants a GUI interface (not a web one!) use some [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) (and these are cross-platform, so your code would be source-portable to other OSes).
- if cross-platform portability matters, consider using C++ frameworks like [Boost](http://boost.org/), [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt).
- installing and using Linux on your own laptop is easy, and Linux is very developer friendly. Read some Linux system programming book (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf)). See also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html).

Notice that WinAPI is proprietary (to Microsoft), but [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is a standard specification (and Linux is de facto mostly POSIX compliant).

> Do i have to develop with mingw?

I recommend to **install and use Linux on your development machine**, then use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and/or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (on the command line, but you'll probably use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)). Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Of course you need to develop for the Linux & POSIX API (not the Windows one).

<sup>(It is adapting your code to Linux & POSIX API that will take you most of the work, not using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which are both quite C99 or C11 or C++11 or C++14 standard compliant, and accept many common options.)</sup>

I also recommend publishing your source code under some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) license on [github](http://github.com/). You might then get some help.

You might be interested by [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) since in some cases you might run a Linux executable on Windows

<sup>(but I don't know the details, since I never used Windows)</sup>

<sup>PS: If you want to compile *for* Windows, it is simpler to keep Windows on your laptop; since [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) is less convenient.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider improving your question by editing it... It is a bit confusing and unclear. See my comments under your question!

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm not good english. I make the sevice that make the program and provide to user. it's windows execute file. but server is linux.  so.. I'm just sorry.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker neither. But please *edit your question*, perhaps with the help of some dictionary from your native language and of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/). I don't understand what you mean by "making the service". What is the relation to [web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)? Don't comment your question, but improve it. If you improve your question, you'll get better answers (and I could improve my answer above)

Answer (score 2):

> > Do i have to develop with mingw?

MinGW is Just a GCC port for Windows operating system, nothing else. I.e. you can compile your Windows specific code directly on Windows or cross compile same code on GNU/Linux and then run executable file on Windows.
GCC - means GNU compiler collection, it has C, C++, Objective C and some another compilers. GCC C compiler is main C compiler used by GNU linux.

> > Can i compile c using visual c on linux?

No you can not since, visual studio C compiler is not ported to GNU/Linux. But you can compile your C code using GCC.

> > But i used many windows apis and i don't faith this answer. (_beginthreadex, FillConsoleOutputCharacter, CreateConsoleScreenBuffer and stuff)

If you need to run your program written for the Windows on your GNU/Linux operating system, you can use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). I.e. compile your exe file on Windows and run it on GNU/Linux as it is.

And in the same time, this is not good idea. It is better to use some standard or cross platform API instead. Then compile it for operating system you'd like to use using any compiler you'd like.

E.G.

1. thrd_create instead of _beginthreadex
2. [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) instead of Windows Console specific functionality

Comment: thank you so much! thank you!